# Rewriting the probability density function as a probability function

Tags: probability, calculus

Letting $dt$ be an infinitesimal interval, what is the argument to that

$$f(t | H_{t_n})\;dt = P (t \in [t,t+dt] | H_{t_n}),$$

where $H_{t_n}$ denotes the history of the previous points before $t$? I know that the probability to be in a certain interval is by integrating the density function over that interval. But why is it in this case equal to the density function times the length of the interval? I've gotten an explanation that it's because we can assume that the density function is constant, as we are considering an infinitesimal interval. However, I can see that the equality then is true if the pdf is constant, but I don't understand **why** we can assume that the it is constant when considering an infinitesimal interval.

Comment: This is not an equality unless $dt$ is taken to be a true infinitesimal.  When $dt$ is a standard number (that is, not infinitesimal), this is an *approximate* equality established by the Mean Value Theorem of calculus, *assuming* $f$ is continuous on $[t, t+dt).$

Comment: It is given in the proof, or it is stated, that $dt$ is an infinitesimal interval. But my question is then, why we can assume that the pdf is constant, given that the interval is infinitesimal?

Comment: You need to study the meaning of infinitesimals (something which is rarely taught).  The subject is called "nonstandard analysis."

Comment: @whuber any good references on the topic?

Comment: Nelson; and Herzberg: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848738.